# Improvement on flag files and data files?

Tags: c#, java, c++, architecture

I have a existing project (non-web), with multiple components/programs running on different machines. The programs use flag files e.g. "xxx.request" "xxx.done" to signal each other. And also data files are created and put in a particular directory and passed to another program to process. The data files and flag files are all in a shared storage.

The pros of this approach is that it is really easy to implement. But I feel that this is not good in the long run.

What other alternatives do I have, so that I can make substantial improvement.

Comment: What abilities do you have? Are your applications belong to web?

Comment: @Vladimir Ivanov there is no web component. Mostly I need messaging and data transfer ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a messaging system for sending messages.  Files don't make a good reliable, secure, mangageable, or fast protocol for sending data between applications.  In Java I would use JMS which has many implementations which have C# and C++ clients.

Comment: Is this easy to implement? compare to socket, of IPC?

Comment: A simple socket is easiest to implement but if you want reliability, manageability, monitoring you will quickly find a pre-tested system like JMS is the way to go.